# How to not treat categories as tags in feeds

Tags: categories, tags, feed

Basically we're (ab)using Category to determine whether a post is a News post or a Blog post, and so it's not a category in the traditional sense to the outside world.  I'd like the category to not be indexed by feed-readers/crawlers, only the tags.

I found an easy way to do it with an easy change to 1 function in the core, but [I'd rather avoid that](http://codex.wordpress.org/images/b/b3/donthack.jpg) if possible.

Is there a way to do that without modifying core? (Specifically `get_the_category_rss` in `wp-includes/feed.php`)

EDIT:
What I mean specifically is to not list the category in the feed.  For example, this is what part the current RSS2 feed looks like:

```
<category><![CDATA[blog]]></category>
<category><![CDATA[test]]></category>
<category><![CDATA[testing]]></category>
<category><![CDATA[yeah!]]></category>
```

"blog" is a Wordpress Category, while "test", "testing", and "yeah!" are Wordpress Tags.

What I want is to exclude the entry `<category><![CDATA[blog]]></category>` entirely from the feed.  The same should apply to Atom feeds and any others.

Comment: Do you want to prevent indexing of category feed by services only or kill this part of functionality completely?

Comment: Well, as far as I can tell in the feed output it looks like it's treating the category the same way it's treating tags.  Basically in the feed I don't want the category to be outputted.  Category in our case doesn't carry the same semantic meaning as normal categories.

Comment: Yes, I understand. I ask what exactly do you want to happen - category links to not being displayed on front-end, category feeds contain no items, category feeds result in 404 error, something else?

Comment: Tried to clarify what I meant in the edit.  Let me know if that's not clear enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tricky. It lumps categories and tags together pretty good. Had couple of approaches here is least messy:

```
add_filter('the_category_rss', 'remove_rss_categories');

function remove_rss_categories( $the_list ) {

    $categories = get_the_category();

    foreach ($categories as $category)
        $the_list = str_replace("<category><![CDATA[{$category->name}]]></category>", '', $the_list);

    return $the_list;
}
```

Comment: Good call on add_filter.  I didn't know about that.

Answer (score 0):

@Rarst got me on the right track.  I modified it to work on all the different types of feed with some copy/paste/modify from the exact code used in the WP core to make sure escaping is done in the same way etc.

Please give @Rarst the +1's, as it's really his solution.  Just posting this as a more complete solution.  I added this to my theme's `function.php` file and it did the trick.

NOTE that this could break in future if WP changes the format of the feeds.  This is working as of WP 3.0

```
add_filter('the_category_rss', 'remove_rss_categories', 10, 2); 

function remove_rss_categories( $the_list, $type ) {
    if ( empty($type) )
      $type = get_default_feed();

    $categories = get_the_category();    
    $cat_names = array();

    $filter = 'rss';
    if ( 'atom' == $type )
      $filter = 'raw';

    if ( !empty($categories) ) foreach ( (array) $categories as $category ) {
      $cat_names[] = sanitize_term_field('name', $category->name, $category->term_id, 'category', $filter);
    }
    $cat_names = array_unique($cat_names);

    foreach ($cat_names as $cat_name) {

      if ( 'rdf' == $type )
        $the_list .= str_replace("\t\t<dc:subject><![CDATA[$cat_name]]></dc:subject>\n", '', $the_list);
      elseif ( 'atom' == $type )
        $the_list .= str_replace(sprintf( '<category scheme="%1$s" term="%2$s" />', esc_attr( apply_filters( 'get_bloginfo_rss', get_bloginfo( 'url' ) ) ), esc_attr( $cat_name ) ), '', $the_list);
      else
        $the_list = str_replace("\t\t<category><![CDATA[" . @html_entity_decode( $cat_name, ENT_COMPAT, get_option('blog_charset') ) . "]]></category>\n", '', $the_list);
    }
    return $the_list;
}
```

Comment: One note from quick look, change first line to `add_filter('the_category_rss', 'remove_rss_categories', 10, 2);` because you need two arguments (`$the_list, $type`) to be passed to function and it defaults to one.

Comment: Ah thanks.  It seemed to work without it, but I guess it's only used to determine the type of sanitation to use, so it could very well be coincidence that it worked.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I made category removal with such code in functions.php:

```
add_filter( 'the_category_rss', 'remove_category_from_rss', 10, 2 );
function remove_category_from_rss( $the_list, $type ){
    return;
}
```